# How to make 2 circles travelling in opposite directions?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a HTML program where I want to have two circles traveling on a circular path, in opposite directions. That's the main idea. Here's my code so far (I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e6CG2lGtdus) on circular movement coding, and stopped right at 8:35 when it's just the red circle in motion):

styles.css:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

.circle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #262626;
}

.line{
    width: 50%;
    height: 2px;
    background: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 1px);
    transform-origin: right;
    animation: animate 1s linear infinite;
}

.line:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #f00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: -10px;
    left: -11px;
}

@keyframes animate{
    0%{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Two Circles in Circular Motion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "circle">
      <div class = "line"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Right now I only have 1 circle. I want to create another one, and animate it so that it travels in the same circular path but in the opposite direction. I'm relatively new to CSS and HTML, so can someone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can optimize your code and use only one div and its pseudo element for the small circles:

```css
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #262626;
  /* place both item to the center */
  display:grid;
  align-content:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.circle::before,
.circle::after {
  content: '';
  grid-area:1/1; /* both will overlap */
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform:rotate(0deg) translate(200px) rotate(0deg);
  animation:animate 2s linear infinite;
}
.circle::after {
  animation-direction:reverse; /* the opposite animation for the after */
  background:blue;
}

@keyframes animate {
  100% {transform:rotate(360deg) translate(200px) rotate(-360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is you could have made another line and used
`animation-direction: reverse;` on it.

Example;

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #262626;
}

.line, .line2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
  transform-origin: right;
  animation: animate 1s linear infinite;
}

.line:before, .line2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -10px;
  left: -11px;
}

.line2 {
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
</div>
```

You also could have created another line (like I did in my example (line2)), and bound a different animation keyframe to it like below;

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #262626;
}

.line {
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
  transform-origin: right;
  animation: animate 1s linear infinite;
}

.line2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
  transform-origin: right;
  animation: animate2 1s linear infinite;
}

.line:before, .line2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -10px;
  left: -11px;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
</div>
```

There are many possibilities to achieve what you are looking for :)

Because you say you are new to HTML and CSS I figured I'd show you some alternatives.